Space of square-integrable functions and its scalar product
For square integrable functions we define a scalar product: $$\int{d^3x \psi^* (\vec{x}) \phi (\vec{x})}$$
for any $\psi, \phi \in L^2(V) $.
How can I show that the fundamental property $(\psi,\phi)=(\phi, \psi)^*$ of scalar product is valid for the expression above? I want to demonstrate that for square integrable functions the conjugate of an integral is equal to the integral of the conjugate.

Properties of the conjugate needed to prove it:
$\hspace{6cm}\textbf{1.}\;\left(\displaystyle\sum_i z_i\right)^\ast=\displaystyle\sum_i z_i^\ast\sim \left(\displaystyle\int z\right)^\ast=\displaystyle\int z^\ast$
$\hspace{6cm}\textbf{2.}\; (z_1z_2)^\ast=z_1^\ast z_2^\ast$
$\hspace{6cm}\textbf{3.}\; (z^\ast)^\ast=z$
Thus,
$$(\psi,\phi)=\int\mathrm d^3\mathbf x\,\psi^\ast(\mathbf x)\phi(\mathbf x)\overset{(2)+(3)}{=}\int\mathrm d^3\mathbf x\,(\psi (\mathbf x)\phi^\ast(\mathbf x))^\ast\overset{(1)}{=}\left(\int\mathrm d^3\mathbf x\,\phi^\ast(\mathbf x)\psi (\mathbf x)\right)^\ast=(\phi,\psi)^\ast$$
